# Issue in removing a special character from regex to format the phone number

Tags: regex, reporting-services

Working to format the phone number in .rdl reporting. I have below Regex in the expression property of the report field.
**Possible inputs from user - 720) 352-6511 , +1 (469) 292-4242, 310.614.1316, (310) 468-0516**

**desired Output -  (303) 233-2345**

```
My regex =System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(IIf(IsNothing(Fields!Contact_Phone.Value), "", Fields!Contact_Phone.Value), "(\d{3})[ -.]*(\d{3})[ -.]*(\d{4})", "($1) $2-$3")
```

**My output - ((303) 233-2345**

There is an extra open parenthesis at the starting, the other options i tired are not working.

Thanks

Comment: So, if there is `+1` prefix, should it stay or should it be removed?

Comment: That's not JavaScript. Please tag this with the correct language.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew +1 should be removed as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very generic approach to fixing this issue: match any non-digit chars between the possible items in the input text and capture the three parts that look obligatory in the input:

```cs
^[^\d+]*(?:\+\D*\d+\D+)?(\d{3})\D*(\d{3})\D*(\d{4})\D*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dexfFk/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^\d+]*` - zero or more chars other than digits and `+`
- `(?:\+\D*\d+\D+)?` - an optional sequence of `+`, zero or more non-digits, one or more digits, one or more non-digits
- `(\d{3})` - Group 1: three digits
- `\D*` - zero or more non-digits
- `(\d{3})` - Group 2: three digits
- `\D*` - zero or more non-digits
- `(\d{4})` - Group 3: four digits
- `\D*` - zero or more non-digits
- `$` - end of string.